# Devise: JSON Message on Sesson#Destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, devise

I am trying to get a JSON response message on logout for Devise in a Rails 5 application.

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    around_action :after_logout_message


    protected

    def after_logout_message
        set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_out
        yield
    end



    private

    def respond_to_on_destroy
        # We actually need to hardcode this as Rails default responder doesn't
        # support returning empty response on GET request
        respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render json: flash }
            format.any(*navigational_formats) { redirect_to after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name) }
        end
    end
end
```

and in my routes file

```
get 'login', to: 'sessions#new', as: :new_user_session
post 'login', to: 'sessions#create', as: :user_session
match 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_user_session, via: Devise.mappings[:user].sign_out_via
```

Why doesn't this work? Every other action seems to handle this well.

Comment: Does anything change if you put the `flash[:notice]` line *after* the yield?

Comment: Yes, that works when I set a flash manually like ```flash[:notice] = something```. But when I change it to ```set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_out``` it doesn't work. Any idea why or should I post another question?

Comment: Update: It shows from the rails console using ```app.flash```, but trying to cURL still returns nothing (when doing ```flash[:notice] = "test"```).

Comment: Sounds like it'd be worth a new question. I googled the docs (http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/DeviseController%3Aset_flash_message) on the off-chance it was just a "set `flash.now`" problem, but looks like you have to do that deliberately, so probably not that...

Comment: Yeah I don't know that the json version will actually return the flash... :/ but I've never tried...